# magento set the value of an attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have created a new attribute serial number for all the products. Now I don't know how to set its value when order is completed. I know where to change it but I don't have the function. Here is the code. The new attribute have the code "serial_number".

```
if($status == 'complete'){

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
      // Here I want to update the value, I am sure something like the following will work.         
      $this->setAttribute($item, 'serial_number', '123');

}
}
```

Also what should be the settings for it in admin. I am changing the value when the status for the order is changed to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be setting the attribute, but where is the code to save() the item to the db

```
if($status == 'complete'){   
    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
         $item->setSerialNumber('123');
         $item->save()   
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R.S, Its my fault. How to update value if we have textarea for serialNumber? Also in which table the attributes belong to.

Comment: Where is the textarea, do you want display the value in the admin? Create a new question with more info on what your trying to accomplish because you may be able to use product `additional_options` to store the values

Comment: Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649783/magento-set-the-new-attribute-value

Answer (score 5):

here's how you do it differently: (color = attribute name, red = attribute value_id)

Let's start assuming you already have $product available.

```
$attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
$avid = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId('red');
$product->setData('color', $avid);
$product->save();
}
```

Comment: and `if (!attr->usesSource()) { $product->setData('color','red'); $product->save(); }` ?

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using following code -

```
if($status == 'complete'){

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {

         $item->setSerialNumber('123');

     }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I already tried it, but not working for me. I don't know what I am missing.