# Magento set the new attribute value

Tags: php, magento

I have created a new IMEI attribute of type textarea for all products, see from the image. Can anyone point out a function to update the its value. I have the code like the following.

$this belogns to Mage_Sales_Model_Order.

```
    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {

                 $item->setImei('123');

             $item->save();
             echo $item->getImei();
    }
```

I am getting 123 from the last statement but when I am viewing from admin. Its not changing there. Also in which table the attribute and value will be stored, So I can debug from there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What class is `$this->getAllItems()` is it `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`?

If it not `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` then load the product by id and save the product

```
foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId() or $item->getProductId())
     $product->setImei($product->getImei() . '123');

     $product->save();   
}
```

Comment: $this belogns to Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Comment: Why do you want to add information about an order to a product? Why dont you create a custom module with a db to keep track of IMEI #?

Comment: I want to integrate my products with a third party website. So I added an attribute here to track the products. We are displaying the first imei number from the imei field on our store when the user click on a phone from third party website and when the purchase is completed we will have to remove the first imei number from the list so the next will be available for sale. But your propose solution is also good, because I think we need to handle every imei number seperatly.

Comment: Depending on the amount of IMEI, you could make each imei a simple product of a configurable product

Comment: It can also be a choice. But the value still not updating also with the above code.

Comment: Hard code the product id, and trying changing the sku (`$product->setSku($product->getsku() . 'rs123');`). If that work the double check the name of the imei field and the product id

Answer (score 1):

The values of catalog product attributes of type text are stored in the table `catalog_product_entity_text`. An SQL would be

```
select * from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id = {insert your attribute id} and entity_id = {insert your product id}
```

The query will return results for every store view in the system.

The reason why you do not see a change to the attribute in the backend is probably because the new value is set for a different website/store than the one loaded in the backend.

You are already using a correct way to set the attribute value assuming $item is of type Mage_Catalog_Model_Product:

```
$item->setImei('123');
$item->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

heres how you do it differently: (color = attribute name, red = attribute value id)

starts assuming you already have $product available.

```
$attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');

            if ($attr->usesSource()) {

               $avid = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId('red');

               $product->setData('color', $avid);
               $product->save();
            }
```